# Android: Проблема с AdMob

Tags: java, android, admob

Такая фигня: вставил рекламу в приложение (AdMob 6.3.0.), по всем правилам..

```
 @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        if(adView == null)
        {
            // Create the adView
            adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER,LabelsShow.AD_UNIT_ID_GOES_HERE);
            // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
            // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.l_eadds);
            // Add the adView to it
            layout.addView(adView);
            // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
        }
    }
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"

              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/l_eadds"
            android:background="@drawable/bgg"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="53dip" android:background="@drawable/bg_fill">
        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="47dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dp" android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"

                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/e"/>
            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/search"
                    android:id="@+id/look" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView" android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                    android:minWidth="100dip" android:background="@drawable/btn_no"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp" android:layout_marginTop="6dp" android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"/>
        </TableRow>
    </LinearLayout>
    <WebView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/webView" android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

            android:layout_below="@+id/look">
        <requestFocus />
            </WebView>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="E"
            android:id="@+id/textViewik" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginTop="19dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

И проблема очень не обычная: дело в том,что на некоторых устройствах реклама не показывается. Проверял на 4 устройствах.
2 на Андроид 2.3. и 2 на Андроид 4.0.
На устройствах с Андроид 4.0. реклама работает безупречно. 
На 2.3. активити сначала немного тупит,а потом появляется: и рекламы нету. Просто пустая область без ничего. 
В чём может быть проблема?
В других приложениях реклама есть.

Comment: Тоже интересна данная тема, ибо не знаю, как лечить в своей прилоге.

Comment: Ничего страшного... появится когда подгрузится...

Comment: Просто делайте баннер в xml. Не будет проблем.

Comment: Может это знак убрать её нафиг? :-D